# Mongoose Jasminejs unit test crud methods (DAO)

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I am building a Nodejs + Mongoose + MongoDB web application and i am trying to unit test my DAO methods with Jasmine unit test framework.

My model is the following :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var profilSchema = new Schema({
photo: {type: String},
nom: {type: String , required: true},
type: { type: String , required: true},
descriptif: {type: String, required: true},
niveauScolaire: {type: String , required: true},

});

/**
* Statics
*/
 profilSchema.statics = {
load: function(id, cb) {
    this.findOne({
        _id: id
    }).exec(cb);
}
  };

  var Profil = mongoose.model('Profil', profilSchema);
```

In my DAO function that is responsible for displaying all profiles i have the following code

```
/**
 * List of Profiles
 */
  exports.all = function(req, res) {
   Profil.find().exec(function(err, profils) {
    if (err) {
        res.render('error', {
            status: 500
        });
    } else {
        // console.log(profils._id);
        res.jsonp(profils);
    }
});
};
```

in my controller i call a function like this :

```
    $scope.afficherProfils = function() {
    $http.get('/listerProfil')
        .success(function(data) {
        $scope.listeProfils = data;

    });

};
```

How can i test this kind of functions ? Is it possible to insert some elements into the mongoDB database and test if the function gets information ?
I really have no prior experiences in this kind of unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test server side and client side functionality separately.

Angularjs bits are going to run inside the browser. You can use [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html) or [testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem) to run your client side tests. You don't need to make an actual http request in your tests. You can [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) to control the behaviour.

Take a look at how to write jasmine tests and dive into angularjs documentation to get a better understanding of writing unit and e2e tests in for angularjs

Further reading materials:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/09/advanced-testing-and-debugging-in-angularjs.html

node.js bits are going to run on the server side, you can use [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) to run your server side test. Many projects use a separate test database for tests, they populate it with test data before the test suit runs and then cleans the database once the test run is completed.